# ¿PDO en dos INSERT diferentes?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

¿ Es posible realizar dos prepared statements en dos INSERT de diferentes tablas que tengo en un registro, es decir, un prepared para cada uno ?

Por ejemplo, tengo esto:

```
INSERT INTO datos (nombre, email) VALUES('$nombre', '$email');
INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, id_datos) VALUES('$usuario','$password_hash','$idDatos');
```

Comment: Hola @Cifu, Por lo que se no es posible, pero te recomiendo que si vas hacer una inserción como la que deduzco que piensas realizar no le veo problema en que hagas la inserción en una sola tabla y en tu app 'juegues' con los querys para obtener cuyos resultados.......Perdón si no lo es, pero mi intuición es que lo que vas a realizar es que en un lo gin vas a iniciar sesión por medio del email y la contraseña por lo que luego vas a a tener que decir ¿como hago dos selects? igualmente si es por usuario no veo porque no meter el nombre y el email en una sola tabla..espero me hayas entendido.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir, el caso es que nombre y usuario son cosas distintas. Usuario es con el que hará el login y el nombre es el que mostrará en su panel, he pensado en meter todo en una tabla pero siento que me es más desordenado todo y me descuadra toda la web. En un select sé que no es problema hacerlo pues con un JOIN lo soluciono rápido, el problema son los insert. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Ok te entiendo, ps yo personalmente he trabajado asi como te explique y todo me anda normal y no tengo inconvenientes...espero puedas hallar la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Al final he optado por tu solución Daniel, lo he pensado y creo que es lo más adecuado, he hecho un tabla con todos los datos del registro. Mil gracias!

Comment: Ok con gusto....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar dos prepared statements sin necesidad de ejecutar uno para declarar el otro:

```
$insert1 = "INSERT INTO datos (nombre, email) VALUES(:nombre, :email);";
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, id_datos) VALUES(:usuario,:password_hash,:idDatos);";

$statement1 = $conn->prepare($insert1);
$statement2 = $conn->prepare($insert2);

$statement1->bindValue(':nombre', $nombre, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
$statement1->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
```